# ThreadPoolExecutor without a Queue

Tags: java, queue, threadpool

I want to create a fixed-size thread pool that admits no task into its queue. In other words, if the thread pool is currently in use, the incoming task should be rejected outright. Based on the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html), one way to do this, in my opinion, would be to create a dummy Queue object which refuses to admit a task. What is the idiomatic way to accomplish this in Java?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) in your ThreadPoolExector which is a queue which holds no objects.  The cached thread pool uses this because it creates new threads on demand.

If it cannot be queued but I would suggest using the [RejectedExecutionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html) to run the task in the current thread. This way it will always be run "immediately".

BTW: It would be useful to make it clear why you want to do this.

Comment: We have a use case for this now. If some node has a free worker it can take new task, otherwise some other node will take it, but the task should not be queued. If queued then no chance for another node.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to create a fixed-size thread pool that admits no task into its queue.

For posterity, if you need a thread-pool that does not have a queue *and* does run all of the jobs (slightly different than the OP), then you can use the `SynchronousQueue` which will block until a thread is ready for the job.  The trick is to use a `RejectedExecutionHandler` which calls `put(...)` on the queue which will block.

```
threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize,
  keepAliveTime, unit, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(),
  new RejectedExecutionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable runnable,
           ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
      if (executor.isShutdown()) {
        throw new RejectedExecutionException("pool already shutdown");
      }
      try {
        // this needs to be put(...) and not add(...)
        executor.getQueue().put(runnable);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
    }
  });
```

You will be able to submit jobs until the `maximumPoolSize` number of threads is reached and then the submitting will block until a job finishes and a thread is available to de-queue from the `SynchronousQueue`.

NOTE: After the thread pool is shutdown any `Runnable`s that are submitted must throw `RejectedExecutionException`  otherwise they will block indefinitely in `executor.getQueue().put(...)` waiting for an idle thread.

Comment: Hey @hertzsprung, I appreciate the edit but I would have rather done it is as a _comment_ instead of editing my answer.

Comment: Hi @Gray, I admit I'm not super clear on SO etiquette, I'll comment in future.

Comment: I also see you've re-edited the information about interrupting threads during shutdown.  The `RejectedExecutionHandler` must throw `RejectedExecutionException`, not the `Runnable`s themselves.  `executor.getQueue().put()` blocks indefinitely once the pool is shut down, so the only way to unblock is to interrupt the blocked thread(s).

Answer (score -1):

Can you elaborate as to why you want to do such a thing?  The fundamental purpose of a TP + Q is to have an automatic "holding mechanism" for work and decouple the workers from the work creation process.  If your intent is to only have as many acceptable work packages as workers then you dont really need a TPE.

Comment: The task can be picked up another thread pool executor with free threads, rather than waiting in the queue of the former. What should I be using instead of a ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: If you want to control the execution then TPE is not your choice.  You are better off having a simple collection of worker threads to which you can hand off the job (if they are available) a simple Set<FreeWorkers> that you construct and pull / push theads in and out of it from the main thread.